# Pass model values to controller in using jQuery Post ()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The application is in .Net framework 3.5 and MVC framework 2.0 for .Net framework 3.5. I have a view which in $.post passes parameters. I also need that $.post , passes model values to controller.

In the view below , how do I pass model in the $.post function, so that the controller gets the value of the Textbox. I need the button and not submit button.

The view is:

```
<div>
        <label for ="Name"> Name</label> &nbsp; <%=@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
        <select id ="prod" style ="width:150px">
            <option value ="GL">GL</option>
            <option value = "Property"> Property</option>
            <option value = "Package">Package</option>
            <option value = "Island">Island</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="button" id="btnPost" value = "GetValue" />
</div>
```

```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" >
         $(function() {
         $("#btnPost").click(function() {
        alert("here" + $("#prod").val());
        $.post("/Transfer/DisplayText", { "str1": $("#prod").val()},
           function(data) {
           alert("success");
       });
    });

});
```

Th controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayText(string 
       str1,TestPost_AjaxMVC.ViewModels.TransferViewModel model)
     {
        string str2 = str1;
        return View("Transfer");
     }
```

The model is :

```
 public class TransferViewModel
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything is ok in your code just replace

```
$.post
```

to `$.get`
Because you are returning a view from your controller also use Url.action
like below because it may not work when you publish the project

```
$.get('<%=Url.Action("DisplayText","Transfer")%>', { str1: $("#prod").val()},
           function(data) {
           alert("success");
       });
```

You should remove double quote from str1.Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I removed the quote from "str1". Changed $.post to $.get and also the controller to [httpGet] The value of str1 is passed but even if I enter some value for the texbox I get model as null in the controller.

Comment: you should use model.name=str1; in your controller you are not passing model values via ajax.only str1

Comment: '@Url.Action("DisplayText","Transfer")', this did not work for me

Comment: why?It should and it is good practice,strongly recommended, can you show the error?

Comment: URL POST @Url.Action(%22DisplayText%22,%22Transfer%22) Status 500 Internal Server Error Domain localhost:61068

Comment: i think you are not using razor, so use  '<%=Url.Action("DisplayText","Transfer")%>'

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify the model and send it as part of data and let MVC use JSON Model Binding

```
$(function() {
   $("#btnPost").click(function() {

    var TransferViewModel={};
    TransferViewModel.Name="SomeData";
    var postData={};
    postData.str1=$("#prod").val();
    postData.model=TransferViewModel;


   $.ajax({
       url:"/Transfer/DisplayText",
       type:"POST",
       data:JSON.stringify(postData),
       contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function(){

       }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: By the example above TransferViewModel.Name="SomeData"; will I have to change my control <%=@Html.TextBoxFor( to <%=@Html.TextBox, or is there a way to get the value <%=@Html.TextBoxFor and pass it to var postdata, in your example above.                                                             Another problem is $.ajax some how does not work for me even the str1 value does not get passed when I use $.ajax, so I had used $.Post. Can you give example with $.Post